# можно ли использовать yarn и npm в одной проекте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarn

У меня были косяки с деплоем обычных тестовых приложений на hiroku и других сервисов, вроде бы делал все правильно, но где то проплывали косяки про использование Yarn и npm в одном проекте. Я только в начале создания большого проекта, хотелось бы не повторить их снова. Я вот использовал пару команд yarn и когда начал использовать firebase при firebase init идет несколько действий и он спрашивает вопрос о том чтобы установить дополнительные зависимости но по дефолту стоит Npm

Comment: В npm подвезли lock файл. Если таких файлов несколько - возникает закономерный вопрос - кому из них верить? Кто правильный? Так что лучше не смешивать.

Comment: @vp_arth значит ли это что они оба будут писать, а в конце один лок файл лучше удалить?

Comment: изначально нужно решить, на чём у вас проект, на yarn или npm, и использовать только его, и не коммитить в  VCS/удалять случайно появившиеся файлы от другого.

Comment: @vp_arth Благодарю!